# South Africa visa complications

Tags: visas, south-africa

curious if anyone has any experience with this. I'm going on an exchange semester to South Africa and would like to travel around the country a bit after the semester ends. Trouble is I'm only granted a visa for as long as the study term. What would be necessary for being able to stay in the country as a tourist? Can I get permission from that inside the country, or will I be able to get some time on a tourist stamp if I leave the country and reenter?

Answer (score 3):

According to [Types of Temporary Residence Permits](http://www.dha.gov.za/index.php/types-of-temp-res-permits):

> The validity period of an exchange permit depends on the length of the programme for which it is issued and usually does not exceed 12 months. Exchange permits can not be renewed or extended.

However, the above is not clear on whether you can be issued a tourist permit after the completion date of your exchange permit. You may need to contact your local SA consulate to get an answer to this question (since the answer may also depend on your nationality).